# Twitter Digits web integration error (error code = 239)

Tags: twitter, twitter-fabric, fabric.io

I have integrated twitter digits with my website which is deployed in cloud. It successfully initialize twitter digits and opens up the window for phone number. But upon pressing send confirmation code button it gives me error error_code=239 i.e. Bad guest token. But I have Initialized Digits successfully using consumer key.